# What type of result is this which i am getting as API response?

Tags: php, arrays, json, function, cakephp-2.0

This is my JSON

`$result=[{CFirst: "test3"},{CLast: "test3"},{CEmail: "test2@gmail.com"}]`

I am getting this as a result of an API request.
I guessed it was json, so tried to `json_decode()`, but it didn't work and `json_last_error()` returned code 4.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is in bad format , you need to enclose them under double quotes like this.

```
[{"CFirst": "test3"},{"CLast": "test3"},{"CEmail": "test2@gmail.com"}]
```

The `CFirst,CLast` & `CEmail` have been wrapped around double quotes for your information.

#### The code..

```
<?php
$json='[{"CFirst": "test3"},{"CLast": "test3"},{"CEmail": "test2@gmail.com"}]';
print_r(json_decode($json,true));
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/129184)

**`EDIT :`**

```
<?php
$result='[{CFirst: "test3"},{CLast: "test3"},{CEmail: "test2@gmail.com"}]';
$result=str_replace(array('{',':'),array('{"','":'),$result); //<--- Add this
print_r(json_decode($result,true));
```

Comment: thanks for your support. But i am getting this as an API response. so if could use it without modifying it, it would be good.

Comment: @user3153222,Check the edited answer , you can directly use an `str_replace()` on your JSON.